# newRichTextValue() after query

Tags: google-sheets

After apply query I want to change some text color via app script, but my query show this error because I changed data, any ways to solve?
To format I used newRichTextValue()

Ty!

[image]

Comment: delete A10:A   ...

Comment: What, sorry I don't understand?

Comment: imagine you have a carpet 3 meters long and you want to roll it out in room that is only 2 meters long - that is exactly what are you doing with query. query needs a space to roll out. if that space is ocupied/full with stuff, query can not roll out and it will throw you an error

Comment: understand, I'll try a diferent way, pick data of query and another tab do the colours :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) mentioned when using [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) you need to have free cells depending on the range that your formula will use, otherwise this error will appear:

`"Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in #range#."`

Solution can be either delete the conflicting cell with your query or move the query to a blank row so it can retrieve the data from your query.